# Convert Unix `cal` output to latex table code: one-liner solution?

Tags: perl, bash, shell, sed, awk

Trying to achieve the following struggled my mind:

Convert Unix `cal` output to latex table code, using a short and sweet one-liner (or few-liner).

E.g `cal -h 02 2012 | $magicline` should yield

```
Mo      &Tu     &We     &Th     &Fr     \\
        &       & 1     & 2     & 3     \\
 6      & 7     & 8     & 9     &10     \\
13      &14     &15     &16     &17     \\
20      &21     &22     &23     &24     \\
27      &28     &       &       &       \\
```

The only reasonable solution I could come up with so far was

```
cal -h | sed -r -e '1d' -e \
  's/^(..)?(...)?(...)?(...)?(...)?(...)?(...)?$/\2\t\&\3\t\&\4\t\&\5\t\&\6\t\\\\/'
```

... and I really tried hard. The nice thing about it being that it's uncomplicated and easy to understand, the bad thing about it that it's "unflexible" (It couldn't cope with a week of 8 days) and a little verbose. I'm looking for alternative solutions to learn from ;-)

**EDIT:** Found another one that seems acceptable

```
cal -h | tail -n +2 |
    perl -ne 'chomp;
        $,="\t&";
        $\="\t\\\\\n";
        $line=$_;
        print map {substr($line,$_*3,3)} (1..5)'
```

**EDIT:** Nice one:

```
cal -h | perl \
    -F'(.{1,3})' -ane \
        'BEGIN{$,="\t&";$\="\t\\\\\n"}
            next if $.==1;
            print @F[3,5,7,9,11]'
```

Comment: Code golf has its own SE forum.

Comment: Which version of `cal` on which platform accepts the `-h` option?

Comment: @Jonathan: the [Ubuntu version of cal](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/gutsy/man1/cal.1.html) appears to be the only one.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: Should perhaps remove `-h`. On Debian, the current day is highlighted, and I believe I once run into the situation where the highlight ANSI codes were not stripped when `stdout` was a pipe. `-h` is only for removing those bytes.

Comment: The title of this question is utterly useless for knowing what it's actually _about_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the GNU version of `awk`:

My output of `cal` using an english `LANG`.

Command:

```
LANG=en_US cal
```

Output:

```
    February 2012   
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
          1  2  3  4
 5  6  7  8  9 10 11
12 13 14 15 16 17 18
19 20 21 22 23 24 25
26 27 28 29
```

---

The `awk` one-line:

```
LANG=en_US cal | awk '
BEGIN { 
  FIELDWIDTHS = "3 3 3 3 3 3 3"; 
  OFS = "&";
} 
FNR == 1 || $0 ~ /^\s*$/ { next } 
{ 
  for (i=2; i<=6; i++) { 
    printf "%-3s%2s", $i, i < 6 ? OFS : "\\\\";
  } 
  printf "\n";
}'
```

Result:

```
Mo  &Tu  &We  &Th  &Fr \\
    &    & 1  & 2  & 3 \\
 6  & 7  & 8  & 9  &10 \\
13  &14  &15  &16  &17 \\
20  &21  &22  &23  &24 \\
27  &28  &29  &    &   \\
```

Comment: good approach, thanks for the `FIELDWIDTHS` bit. How about `cal | awk 'BEGIN{FIELDWIDTHS="3 3 3 3 3 3 3"; OFS="\t&"; ORS="\t\\\\\n";} FNR!=1{print $2,$3,$4,$5,$6;}'` ?

Answer (score 3):

Tested on OS-X:

```
cal 02 2012 |grep . |tail +2 |perl -F'/(.{3})/' -ane \
    'chomp(@F=grep $_,@F); $m=$#F if !$m; printf "%s"."\t&%s"x$m."\t\\\\\n", @F;'
```

Where `cal` output has 3-character columns; `{3}` could be changed to match your `cal` output.

Comment: +1 I don't understand a word, time to learn new perl magic ;-)

Comment: I think `cal -h | perl -F'(.{1,3})' -ane 'BEGIN{$,="\t&";$\="\t\\\\\n"}next if $.==1; print @F[3,5,7,9,11]'` is very exact and "solid". Updated question.

Answer (score 1):

```
cal 02 2012|perl -lnE'$.==1||eof||do{$,="\t&";$\="\t\\\\\n";$l=$_;print map{substr($l,$_*3,3)}(1..5)}'
```

my new favorite:

```
cal 02 2012|perl -F'(.{1,3})' -anE'BEGIN{$,="\t&";$\="\t\\\\\n"}$.==1||eof||do{$i//=@F;print@F[map{$_*2-1}(1..$i/2)]}'
```

Comment: This is THE answer (although only a shorter version of mine ;-])

Comment: Yes it's a modification of your version.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
cal | sed '1d;2{h;s/./ /g;x};/^\s*$/b;G;s/\n/ /;s/^...\(.\{15\}\).*/\1/;s/.../ &\t\&/g;s/\&$/\\\\/'
```

Answer (score -1):

```
cal -h 02 2012| cut -c4-17 | sed -r 's/(..)\s/\0\t\&/g' | sed 's/$/\t\\\\/' | head -n-1 | tail -n +2
```

This will produce:

```
Mo     &Tu     &We     &Th     &Fr    \\
       &       & 1     & 2     & 3    \\
 6     & 7     & 8     & 9     &10    \\
13     &14     &15     &16     &17    \\
20     &21     &22     &23     &24    \\
27     &28     &29     &       &      \\
```

You can easily replace `\t` with number of spaces you wish

Comment: @JoSo, well, it does if you use 4 spaces instead of `\t` as I did pasting output here.

Answer (score -1):

This works for my implementation of `cal`, which uses four-character columns and has an initial title line showing the month and year

```
cal | perl -pe "next if $.==1;s/..../$&&/g;s/&$/\\\\/"
```

It looks as though yours may have eight-character columns and has no title line, in which case

```
cal | perl -pe "s/.{8}/$&&/g;s/&$/\\\\/"
```

should do the trick, but be prepared to tweak it.

Comment: Unfortunately, not creating an empty cell for days that are already in the next month... Though expanding any line at first might fix it. Thanks for the `-p` switch.